# Можно ли в cmake получить сообщение текущего коммита git?

Tags: c++, git, cmake

Пишу консольное приложение на с++ под linux с системой сборки CMake. При запуске приложения оно отображает основную информацию о себе в т.ч. номер версии приложения, который определяется коммитом. Сейчас мне каждый раз приходится изменять эту константу руками (в 90% случаях я просто забываю её менять при очередном коммите). Я хочу что бы при каждой компиляции эта константа определялась автоматически. Самым разумным решением мне кажется заставить Cmake при сборке считывать информацию текущего коммита в которой содержится необходимая строка. Возможно ли как-то сделать это и если возможно то как?

Comment: Ответ @KoVadim отличный, но для количества вариантов добавлю ещё один. Можно использовать [git Hook post-commit](https://githooks.com),      там уже есть id текущего коммита, его также можно записать напрямую в файл, например version.h. Сам Hook может быть написан на любом языке, но удобнее мелкие задачи делать на shell скриптах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создайте себе файл с именем version.cmake (или другое, по вкусу) и добавьте туда такое

```
    exec_program(
      "git"
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
      ARGS "rev-parse HEAD"
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE REL
    )
    configure_file( "version.h.template" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.h" )
```

Дальше создайте файл-шаблон version.h.template

```
 #pragma once

 #define GIT_REL  "${REL}"
```

В свой основной CMakeLists.txt добавьте где то тако

```
add_custom_target( git_version ALL
    "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E chdir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P "version.cmake"
)

add_dependencies( ${PROJECT_NAME} git_version )
```

PROJECT_NAME - это имя проекта, скорректируйте по обстоятельствам.

Теперь при запуске этой зависимости, cmake будет бегать к гиту и забирать версию и добавлять ее в хедер version.h

А что с этой версией Вы будете делать - это уже Ваше дело.

Ещё

- http://xit0.org/2013/04/cmake-use-git-branch-and-commit-details-in-project/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435953/how-can-i-pass-git-sha1-to-compiler-as-definition-using-cmake
- https://bravenewmethod.com/2017/07/14/git-revision-as-compiler-definition-in-build-with-cmake/

Comment: Выглядит как то что нужно, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Написал немного по другому но всё получилось. Большое спасибо за помощь.